# Spring MVC POST submits are not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, weblogic, weblogic12c

My app server is Weblogic 12C and it is working behind an apache proxy.

When I was doing GET submit through the spring MVC form, values are coming to back end, but when I was doing a POST submit, all values comes as null at the backend.

Here is my files.

**JSP File**

```
    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="userForm" action="createUser">

            <form:input path="userInfo.number" readonly="true" maxlength="100"/>
            <form:input path="userInfo.firstName" readonly="true" maxlength="500"/>
            <form:input path="userInfo.lastName" readonly="true" maxlength="500"/>
            <input type="submit" style="font-weight: bold;"                                             value="Send"></td>
</form:form>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="createUser")
    public String createUser(@Valid UserForm userForm,BindingResult result,ModelMap modelMap) {
        LOGGER.debug("Handling POST description" + userForm.getFirstName());
}
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener> 
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>userFormServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring-beans/servlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>userFormServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/apps/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: try with this url /apps/user/createUser or apps/user/createUser.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of this line `userForm.getFirstName()`, it seems that the properties *firstName*, *lastName* and *number* are the properties of the *userForm* object, in that case your form should be

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="userForm" action="createUser">
            <form:input path="number" readonly="true" maxlength="100"/>
            <form:input path="firstName" readonly="true" maxlength="500"/>
            <form:input path="lastName" readonly="true" maxlength="500"/>
            <input type="submit" style="font-weight: bold;"                                             value="Send"></td>
</form:form>
```

maybe slightly different depending on the structure of your *UserForm* class, but you should get a gist of a solution from this

Comment: userForm is having another object called, User userInfo; and the firstName, lastName and the number is mapped to that object.